# Where can I download a description of all system services of Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, service

Where can I download a description of system services of Windows Server 2008? I need a document like this => http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b38a0682-2997-4678-9d9e-a07cc66a3bba&displaylang=en but for Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [Service overview and network port requirements for the Windows Server system](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832017) (KB832017).

Also, Windows Security article, [Controlling Service Security Using Windows Server 2008](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Controlling-Service-Security-Windows-Server-2008.html).

Comment: I have seen this article, but I need a document like this => http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b38a0682-2997-4678-9d9e-a07cc66a3bba&displaylang=en but for Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Maybe you should check this book http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Server-2008-Protocols-Services/dp/073562447X

Comment: After looking at the server 2003 document reference i think KB832017 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832017) would be a good starting point. It has a lot of references and a downloadable XLS that lists the services.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but I guess a good starting point is [Microsoft's Windows Server 2008 product information page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/product-information.aspx), particularly the [White Papers section](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/white-papers.aspx) and [features page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/differentiated-features.aspx).

The following link, for example, leads to a 160 pages longword  document: "[**Windows Server 2008 Technical Overview (full document)**](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/8/d/78d2768f-640a-4e14-a3f8-10835afb0533/Windows%20Server%202008%20Technical%20Overview%20-%20Final.docx)".

For more technical content, there is the [Windows Server 2008 section on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/2008/default.aspx).

Comment: I need a document like this => http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b38a0682-2997-4678-9d9e-a07cc66a3bba&displaylang=en but for Windows Server 2008.

Comment: it's looking like there might not be one published Zhynna. Now I come to think about it, that's not very helful and a rather curious error on Microsoft's part?

Comment: My friend who works at Microsoft said that there is such document inside of Microsoft. He even promised to send me it, but he did not do this yet :-(

Comment: I contacted MS support. Let's see how good they are. :-)

Comment: Good! See if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a VB Script at [this techtasks site](http://techtasks.com/code/viewbookcode/596) that should help enumerate the available services.

```
' This code prints the list of services on a machine
' ---------------------------------------------------------------
' From the book "Windows Server Cookbook" by Robbie Allen
' ISBN: 0-596-00633-0
' ---------------------------------------------------------------

' ------ SCRIPT CONFIGURATION ------
strComputer = "<ServerName>"  ' e.g. fs-rtp01 (use . for local server)
boolShowDetails = TRUE        ' set to FALSE to display list w/o details
' ------ END CONFIGURATION ---------
set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
set objServices = objWMI.InstancesOf("Win32_Service")

for each objService in objServices
   WScript.Echo objService.Name
   if boolShowDetails = TRUE then
      for each objProp in objService.Properties_
         ' Print out NULL if the property is blank
         if IsNull(objProp.Value) then
            Wscript.Echo " " & objProp.Name & " : NULL"
         else
         ' If the value is an array, we need to iterate through each element
         ' of the array
            if objProp.IsArray = TRUE then
               For I = LBound(objProp.Value) to UBound(objProp.Value)
                  wscript.echo " " & objProp.Name & " : " & objProp.Value(I)
               next
            else
           ' If the property was  not NULL or an array, we print it
                wscript.echo " " & objProp.Name & " : " & objProp.Value
            end if
         end if
      next
      WScript.Echo ""
   end if
next
```

Comment: Thanks for this script, but I need a document like this => http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b38a0682-2997-4678-9d9e-a07cc66a3bba&displaylang=en but for Windows Server 2008.