# List of services installed by default in Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, service

I'd like to know all the services that are installed by default for pretty much all the Windows Server lines, including updates for servicepacks. I've seen this for XP and Vista, but not Server.

Comment: This may satisfy http://serverfault.com/questions/25763/where-can-i-download-a-description-of-all-system-services-of-windows-server-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on server version; Core & Standard for example have different services.

About the only thing I found was a listing of Server Core services;
http://msmvps.com/blogs/ad/archive/2008/11/06/windows-server-2008-server-core-default-services.aspx

I don't have a new install of 2008 handy to tell you the default services but if you have one you should be able to check. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.